# switching two relays without delay using millis

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an Arduino-uno and two relays. Each relay has two switch on for two seconds at regular intervals.
total loop time relay 1 and relay2 is 1800 seconds.
relay 1 - 2 on,360 off,2 on,600 off,2 on,430 off,2on,402 off.
relay 2 - 12 off, 2 on, 358 off, 2 on, 606 off, 2 on, 478 off, 2 on, 338 off.
Can somebody help me on a code for this please.

Comment: Do both have a total time of 1800, then I suppose they have to be in sync. You can start by making an array or struct with the numbers. The blink without delay example runs at 1 second interval. Use that 1 second interval to check the array or struct. Have you use the 'enum' before to define numbers to actions?

Comment: When the blink without delay is used, the first second is one second after the arduino has turned on. The pinMode for relay 1 sets it off. That means after turning on the arduino or after a reset, relay 1 is off for one second. Is that okay? Assuming that a HIGH turns the relay on and a LOW output turns the relay off.

Comment: Yes, both the relays have a total time of 1800 seconds, and normally HIGH turns the relay off, and LOW turns the relay on. I tried already a few time to work with the blink without delay code (on advise), but I don't know how to code the on and off times in the code - Jerry.

Comment: What about arrays, enum and struct? are you familiar with those?

Comment: Instead of asking me all those questions, which I can only answer partly, because my little knowledge in this field. Is it not easier for someone to give me a workable sketch, so that I can try and play with it? Or is this to difficult or not possible?

Answer (score 2):

this is a typical application for [Blink Without Delay](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)

Answer (score -1):

```
// Turn leds on and off at certain times.
//
// When the digital output pin is HIGH, then the relay is off.
// When the digital output pin is LOW, then the relay is on.

enum actionEnum {
  RELAY1_ON,
  RELAY1_OFF,
  RELAY2_ON,
  RELAY2_OFF,
};

struct tableStruct {
  unsigned int time;
  actionEnum action;
} const table[] = {
  { 0, RELAY1_ON},
  { 2, RELAY1_OFF},
  { 2 + 360, RELAY1_ON},
  { 2 + 360 + 2, RELAY1_OFF},
  { 2 + 360 + 2 + 600, RELAY1_ON},
  { 2 + 360 + 2 + 600 + 2, RELAY1_OFF},
  { 2 + 360 + 2 + 600 + 2 + 430, RELAY1_ON},
  { 2 + 360 + 2 + 600 + 2 + 430 + 2, RELAY1_OFF},
  // remaining 402 for a total of 1800
  { 0, RELAY2_OFF},         // not needed, it is already off
  { 12, RELAY2_ON},
  { 12 + 2, RELAY2_OFF},
  { 12 + 2 + 358, RELAY2_ON},
  { 12 + 2 + 358 + 2, RELAY2_OFF},
  { 12 + 2 + 358 + 2 + 606, RELAY2_ON},
  { 12 + 2 + 358 + 2 + 606 + 2, RELAY2_OFF},
  { 12 + 2 + 358 + 2 + 606 + 2 + 478, RELAY2_ON},
  { 12 + 2 + 358 + 2 + 606 + 2 + 478 + 2, RELAY2_OFF},
  // remaining 338  for a total of 1800
};

const unsigned int totalTime = 1800;  // total amount of seconds for sequence
unsigned int seconds;

unsigned long previousMillis;
const unsigned long interval = 1000;  // 1000 ms is one second

const int relay1Pin = 2;
const int relay2Pin = 3;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // The relay is off when the pin is high.
  // Turn output high before setting the pinMode.
  // Then the output changes from a floating pin to high,
  // and the relais will not be activated.
  digitalWrite(relay1Pin, HIGH);
  pinMode(relay1Pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relay2Pin, HIGH);
  pinMode(relay2Pin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // A one-second timer with millis
  if (millis() - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis += interval;

    // Scan table
    for (int i = 0; i < int(sizeof(table) / sizeof(tableStruct)); i++) {
      if (table[i].time == seconds) {
        switch (table[i].action) {
          case RELAY1_ON:
            Serial.println("Relay 1 on");
            digitalWrite(relay1Pin, LOW);  // low = relay on
            break;
          case RELAY1_OFF:
            Serial.println("Relay 1 off");
            digitalWrite(relay1Pin, HIGH);  // high = relay off
            break;
          case RELAY2_ON:
            Serial.println("Relay 2 on");
            digitalWrite(relay2Pin, LOW);   // low = relay on
            break;
          case RELAY2_OFF:
            Serial.println("Relay 2 off");
            digitalWrite(relay2Pin, HIGH);  // high = relay off
            break;
          default:
            Serial.println("Error, a bug in the sketch");
            break;
        }
      }
    }

    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= totalTime) {
      seconds = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try this, and I will let you know.

Comment: @Jerry I have tested it and confirmed that it is working according to the information that you gave.

Comment: Working perfect, thank you very much, Jerry.

Comment: @Jerry, I'm glad it is working for you. Do you see how it works? Any command can be put into the table. For example: "measure the temperature" or "make a beep". In the one-second-millis timer, the whole table is scanned to check if something needs to be done.